# Using UITabBar outside of the rootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

My application has a sequence of UIViews (with a UINavigationBar) that lead up to a UITabBarController View. These tab bar views should each have UINavigationBars as well. In my research, I have found that due to the nature of UITabBarControllers they should be the rootViewController and that they should not be wrapped in a previous view controller's NavigationBar, as this will lead to problems in the Navigation stack. I've read into seguing from UIView to UITabBarController using the modal method rather than a push, as to to remove the UINavigationBar, but I can't seem to pass data through the TabBarController and NavigationController to the Tab root view through the segue. I get a selector error.

I guess what I'm looking for is advice on a sound approach to take for using a UITabBar where each child view needs NavigationBars and where the UITabBar is segued to from a previous UIView.

Thanks!

Comment: Presenting the tabbar controller is a perfectly valid approach. If you are having issues with that, post relevant details about the issue so people can help you.

Comment: @rmaddy Is it essential that I segue using the "modal" method? Otherwise, the UITabBarController's child views receive the NavigationBar from the rootView's NavigationController.

Comment: It's not essential but pushing a tab controller where each tab has its own nav controller results in two nav bars and a poor user experience.